# Constructor of class with conflicting name

Tags: c++, class, constructor, clang

I am using clang to compile my code using the c++14 dialect. Take the following example:

```
class x
{
    int _i;

public:

    x(int i)
    {
        this->_i = i;
    }
};

void x()
{
}

void f(class x my_x)
{
    // Do something here
}

int main()
{
    /*
     f(x(33)); // Doesn't work
     f(class x(33)); // Doesn't work
    */

    // This works:

    class x my_x(33);
    f(my_x);

    typedef class x __x;
    f(__x(33));
}
```

Here I have a class named `x` whose name conflicts with a function with the same name. To distinguish between `x` the class and `x` the function, one has to use the `class` identifier. This works for me in all situations, but I could never find a way to directly call the constructor for `x`.

In the previous example, I want to provide function `f` with an `x` object by building it on the go. However, if I use `f(x(33))` it interprets it as an ill-formed call to the function `x`, and if I use `f(class x(33))` it just yields a syntax error.

There are obvious workarounds, but I would like to know if there is anything more elegant than typedefing the class x with a temporary alias or explicitly instantiating an item that will annoy me by living in the whole scope of the calling function while I need it only in the line of the function call.

Maybe there is a simple syntax that I am not aware of?

Comment: Not immediately relevant, and plus one for good question, but `typedef class x __x;` is undefined due to double underscore before x.

Comment: What do you mean by undefined? That code compiles for me. I am always using classes that begin with double underscore... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier. Have an enjoyable afternoon refactoring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is a pair of parentheses:

```
f((class x)(33));
```

Or for more parameters, also use uniform initialization:

```
f((class x){1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: Yay!! That was easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh. Wait. But this works only with single argument constructors. Is there a way to get this working on multiple argument constructors as well?

Comment: @MatteoMonti Make a typedef for `class x` and use a function style cast `T(a,b,c)`

Comment: @MatteoMonti Use uniform initialization: `f((class x){1, 2, 3})`, `(1, 2, 3)` will invoke comma operator.

Comment: @StenSoft Wouldn't that create a designated initializer which is only supported in modern C++ compilers as an extension?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, [designated initializers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Designated_initializers) are, well, designated (eg. `{ .x = 1, .y = 2}`).