# C++ struct constructor and function conflict

Tags: c++, macos, freebsd

I'm using C++11 to write a network program on OS X. When I try to call `kevent` **function**, I find it conflict with the `kevent` **struct**. What should I do?

I want to call `kevent` **function** to wait for event instead of calling `kevent` **struct**'s constructor.

**update**

---

I read the answer from [Constructor of class with conflicting name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675004/constructor-of-class-with-conflicting-name)

After add parentheses to `kevent`，it become type cast expression.

I do want to call **function**

this is my code

```
kevent(event_loop_fd_, change_list.data(), 1, event_list.data(), 1, NULL, &timeout_struct)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're using the wrong signature. In your call above you pass 7 parameters, but the kevent function takes 6. There is a function called kevent64 which takes 7 parameters, the last of which is a `const struct timespec*` - maybe this is the function you intended to call?

Comment: Oh, I change `kevent64` to `kevent` but forget change argument.